# jquery force click (href)

Tags: jquery, href

I have this:

```
<li>
 <a href="#" data-content="visit">
  <span class="bf_hover"></span>
  <span>Visit us</span>
 </a>
</li>
```

And I want to automatically open the "Visit Us" link.

How I can do this ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. "Visit Us" is a text node inside of a span. How would one go about "automatically opening" such a thing? What does it mean to "open" it? EDIT: after someone edited your post, I suppose @Hussein's answer below is what you're after.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can trigger a click by doing

```
$('li a').trigger('click');
```

Comment: @jared The question is not specific

Comment: @Hussein - True, but the answer could be more specific. :)

Comment: So all of you think that a `li a` selector is a good thing to propose? Note: I usually shun element-level selectors. :)

Comment: @JaredFarrish the purpose of this answer was to illustrate how a click can be triggered by Jquery, the point about selectors is a matter of common sense.

Answer (score 18):

It looks like jQuery is not able to force the click event for hyperlinks in 100% of the cases and yours is probably one of those.  My way to solve this issue is using the following:

```
$('li a')[0].click();
```

This way, you use it as a DOM element and not as a jQuery object, and it seems to work in many browsers.

Comment: Yes this invokes the code in the `href` attribute where `$().click()` does not. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

set the windows location to the href of the link. Forcing a click will only work if the link is bound to a click event listener. The default behavior of a link is to go to a location when clicked, but a click event listener is not added. Your solution should be the following:

```
<li>
 <a id="mylink" href="#" data-content="visit">
  <span class="bf_hover"></span>
  <span>Visit us</span>
 </a>
</li>

<script>
  window.location = $("#mylink").attr("href");
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

One possibility would be to replace the pound sign in href="#" with the link to the page you would like to take your users, i.e.

```
<li>
 <a href="visit_us.html" data-content="visit">
  <span class="bf_hover"></span>
  <span>Visit us</span>
 </a>
</li>
```

Where "visit_us.html" is the link to the page.